# Can I use "walk with limps" to imply that both legs are in pain or injured?

Tags: phrase-usage, singular-vs-plural, idiomatic-language

I know that, we can say something like

> He had a stiff ankle on the right leg and **walked with a limp**. (self-made sentence)

Now, I am wondering if can I use the plural "limps" to imply he had to move his legs one after the other to move forward:

> He had stiff **ankles** and **walked with limps**. (self-made sentence)

If not, what's the idiomatic way to describe this situation, in which you have to move the legs one by one in a controlled manner so that you can move forward one step.

Comment: this would not make sense.  'limp' refers to the gait, or the way someone walks.  It does not refer to a limb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those situations where English doesn't necessarily make sense.

This sentence is perfectly normal:

> ✔ He walked with **a** *limp*.

This would imply that *limp* is countable. But, syntactically speaking, the word *itself* isn't. (We simply never pluralize the noun *directly*.)

So, we would never say the following:

> ✘ He walked with **two** *limps*.

Instead, we would use the following:

> ✔ He walked and *limped* **twice**.
>   ✔ He walked **in a series of two** *limps*.

In the first version, it's the verb *limp* that's being used. In the second version (it's syntactically correct—although a little odd to refer to a series that consists of just two occurrences of something), the noun *limp* is pluralized but only because it's being modified by an adjectival phrase that comes before it.

---

Note also that because it's not directly countable, this is also wrong:

> ✘ He walked with **one** *limp*.

This means that this is one of those somewhat uncommon cases where we use the indefinite article in front of a mass noun. It's also the case that this particular mass noun can't take the definite article:

> ✘ He walked with **the** *limp*.

---

So, we would not use your version:

> ✘ He walked with *limps*.

However, we could express it differently:

> ✔ He walked **and** *limped*.
>   ✔ He walked **while** *limping*
>   ✔ He walked **in a series of** *limps*.

Note that, this time, using *series* isn't awkward because the implication is that there were a lot more than just two instances of limping.

---

One other reason why *he walked with limps* sounds strange is not because of us not  pluralizing the noun directly, but because it almost sounds as if *limps* is the name of a person—making the interpretation (which, in context, is obviously wrong) *he walked alongside Limps*.

---

If you want to emphasize a problem with each of his legs, rather than a particular number of instances of limping, you could say:

> ✔ He walked with **a** *limp* **in each leg**.
>   ✔ He walked and *limped* **on both legs**.